# No Visible @interface for 'webview' error

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

I'm getting this error for this line of code:

```
 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

> no visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector
>   'StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:'

I'm really new to this, any ideas?

Comment: How is defined `self.webView`? Is it `UIView` or a `UIWebView` object?

Comment: Please copy and paste _both_ your code _and_ the error, since `stringBy..` != `StringBy...` (note the capitalization)